# finding duplicate values is not working properly

Tags: r

I have a table like below and I want to find duplicates values in few columns . so finding duplicate is working but if any is coming thrice or four time then every time it should show duplicate.

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","KTN2252","ANA2548","DEV2698","HRT2921",NA,"KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ANA2548","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                 city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","triv","vish","del","mum","bang","vish","bhop","kol","noi","gurg"),
                 email = c("akash.dev@gmail.com","rahul.singh@gmail.com",NA,NA,NA,NA,"sanu.ali@gmail.com","kunal.singh@gmail.com","lakhan.tomar@gmail.com","sanu.ali@gmail.com","sarman.ali@gmail.com","zuber.khan@gmail.com","giriraj.singh@gmail.com","pooja.pawar@gmail.com","pooja.pawar@gmail.com","nikita.sharma@gmail.com"),
                 Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","sharma,nikita","ali,sarman","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","sharma,nikita","sharma,nikita"))


colss <- c("ID","email","Name")

df <- df %>% mutate(
  across(.cols= colss,
         .fns = duplicated,
         .names = "{c(1,5,9)}. unique {col}"))
```

The output should  show all values as if it comes more than once.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%in%` in combination with `duplicated`.

```
df$IDDup <- df$ID %in% df$ID[duplicated(df$ID)]
df
#        ID city                   email           Name IDDup
#1  DEV2962  del     akash.dev@gmail.com      dev,akash FALSE
#2  KTN2252  mum   rahul.singh@gmail.com    singh,rahul  TRUE
#3  KTN2252  nav                    <NA>   abbas,salman  TRUE
#4  ANA2548  pun                    <NA>        lal,ram  TRUE
#5  DEV2698 bang                    <NA>    singh,nkunj FALSE
#6  HRT2921 chen                    <NA>  sharma,nikita FALSE
#7     <NA> triv      sanu.ali@gmail.com     ali,sarman FALSE
#8  KTN2624 vish   kunal.singh@gmail.com    singh,kunal FALSE
#9  ANA2548  del  lakhan.tomar@gmail.com   tomar,lakhan  TRUE
#10 ITI2535  mum      sanu.ali@gmail.com thakur,praveen FALSE
#11 DEV2732 bang    sarman.ali@gmail.com     ali,sarman FALSE
#12 HRT2837 vish    zuber.khan@gmail.com     khan,zuber FALSE
#13 ANA2548 bhop giriraj.singh@gmail.com  singh,giriraj  TRUE
#14 KTN2542  kol   pooja.pawar@gmail.com  sharma,lokesh FALSE
#15 ANA2813  noi   pooja.pawar@gmail.com  sharma,nikita FALSE
#16 ITI2210 gurg nikita.sharma@gmail.com  sharma,nikita FALSE
```

or combine two `duplicated` with `|` where one is using `fromLast = TRUE`:

```
duplicated(df$ID) | duplicated(df$ID, fromLast = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[13]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And for more than one columns, also checking for `NA`:

```
colss <- c("ID","email","Name")
colss <- setNames(colss, paste0(c(1,5,9), ".duplicate_", colss))
cbind(df, sapply(colss, function(i) ifelse(
  !is.na(df[[i]]) & df[[i]] %in% df[[i]][duplicated(df[[i]])],
  paste0("duplicate_", i), "")))

df
#        ID city                   email           Name 1.duplicate_ID 5.duplicate_email 9.duplicate_Name
#1  DEV2962  del     akash.dev@gmail.com      dev,akash                                                  
#2  KTN2252  mum   rahul.singh@gmail.com    singh,rahul   duplicate_ID                                   
#3  KTN2252  nav                    <NA>   abbas,salman   duplicate_ID                                   
#4  ANA2548  pun                    <NA>        lal,ram   duplicate_ID                                   
#5  DEV2698 bang                    <NA>    singh,nkunj                                                  
#6  HRT2921 chen                    <NA>  sharma,nikita                                    duplicate_Name
#7     <NA> triv      sanu.ali@gmail.com     ali,sarman                  duplicate_email   duplicate_Name
#8  KTN2624 vish   kunal.singh@gmail.com    singh,kunal                                                  
#9  ANA2548  del  lakhan.tomar@gmail.com   tomar,lakhan   duplicate_ID                                   
#10 ITI2535  mum      sanu.ali@gmail.com thakur,praveen                  duplicate_email                 
#11 DEV2732 bang    sarman.ali@gmail.com     ali,sarman                                    duplicate_Name
#12 HRT2837 vish    zuber.khan@gmail.com     khan,zuber                                                  
#13 ANA2548 bhop giriraj.singh@gmail.com  singh,giriraj   duplicate_ID                                   
#14 KTN2542  kol   pooja.pawar@gmail.com  sharma,lokesh                  duplicate_email                 
#15 ANA2813  noi   pooja.pawar@gmail.com  sharma,nikita                  duplicate_email   duplicate_Name
#16 ITI2210 gurg nikita.sharma@gmail.com  sharma,nikita                                    duplicate_Name
```

Comment: actually i want to mutate my original dat frame with mutated column showing duplicate values . please see my required output.  also if you think i can modify my code please let me know

Comment: You can make this with `cbind`. See update.

Comment: Thanks , this is required just one question . how can i modify my mutated column names like  .names = "{c(1,5,9)}. unique {col}"). and also in place of true /False  i want duplicate and ""

Answer (score 1):

using `mutate(across..` as you desire-

- Since `duplicated` results in TRUE for second record onwards, I have used it in combination with another `duplicated(., fromLast = T)` backwards.
- To eliminate `NA`s I also used `!is.na(.)`
- thus, `((duplicated(.) | duplicated(., fromLast = T)) & !is.na(.))` will result in TRUE/FALSE as we desire
- adding 1 to these will convert F/T to 1,2
- and as such either `''` or `paste(cur_column(), 'duplicated')` will be returned in mutate
- `.names` argument is also used so that existing columns are not mutated in place.

Hope the syntax is clear

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(!city, ~ c('', paste(cur_column(), 'duplicated'))[1+((duplicated(.) | duplicated(., fromLast = T)) & !is.na(.)) ],
                .names = '{.col}_dup'))

        ID city                   email           Name        ID_dup        email_dup        Name_dup
1  DEV2962  del     akash.dev@gmail.com      dev,akash                                               
2  KTN2252  mum   rahul.singh@gmail.com    singh,rahul ID duplicated                                 
3  KTN2252  nav                    <NA>   abbas,salman ID duplicated                                 
4  ANA2548  pun                    <NA>        lal,ram ID duplicated                                 
5  DEV2698 bang                    <NA>    singh,nkunj                                               
6  HRT2921 chen                    <NA>  sharma,nikita                                Name duplicated
7     <NA> triv      sanu.ali@gmail.com     ali,sarman               email duplicated Name duplicated
8  KTN2624 vish   kunal.singh@gmail.com    singh,kunal                                               
9  ANA2548  del  lakhan.tomar@gmail.com   tomar,lakhan ID duplicated                                 
10 ITI2535  mum      sanu.ali@gmail.com thakur,praveen               email duplicated                
11 DEV2732 bang    sarman.ali@gmail.com     ali,sarman                                Name duplicated
12 HRT2837 vish    zuber.khan@gmail.com     khan,zuber                                               
13 ANA2548 bhop giriraj.singh@gmail.com  singh,giriraj ID duplicated                                 
14 KTN2542  kol   pooja.pawar@gmail.com  sharma,lokesh               email duplicated                
15 ANA2813  noi   pooja.pawar@gmail.com  sharma,nikita               email duplicated Name duplicated
16 ITI2210 gurg nikita.sharma@gmail.com  sharma,nikita                                Name duplicated
```

---

the above is equivalent to using wherein `colss` has been provided as an positive list instead of `!city`

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(colss, ~ c('', paste(cur_column(), 'duplicated'))[1+((duplicated(.) | duplicated(., fromLast = T)) & !is.na(.)) ],
                .names = '{.col}_dup'))
```

Comment: I have many columns in dataframe except city , how can i exclude many columns then

Comment: In that case, instead of providing columns to eliminate i.e. `!city` you may provide a columns list on which across is to be performed `colss`